# Laravel groupBy using Carbon - unexpectedly limiting grouped array length

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

```
    $results = Result::orderBy("created_at", "asc")
    ->whereBetween('created_at', array($from, $to))
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($date) use($interval) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format($interval);
    });
```

I'm trying to group sets of results into days/weeks/months depending on what the user selects on the frontend.

The above works in returning the results in groups however its adding a weird limitation.

Lets say that my `$from/$to` spans a period of 2 years.

If `$interval` is 'd' then it only returns 31 groups (31 days in a month). So it should only return the first 31 days as groups.

If `$interval` is 'W' then it only returns 52 groups (52 weeks in a year). So it should only return the first 52 weeks as groups.

If `$interval` is 'm' then it only returns 12 groups (12 months in a year). So it should only return the first 12 months as groups.

I cant find any explanation as to why its implementing these limits to the number of grouped results. Lots of people seem to be using this method to group by date but i cant find anyone else referencing the same issue.

Comment: So is the problem that the 12 month groups don't have results from both years or did you expect 24 month groups instead?

Comment: I'm expecting there to be 24 groups but it's limiting it to 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by X and then year otherwise you're putting values from both years in the same bucket.

If you group by month for example you'll end up having values from January 2017 alongside values from January 2016 since they both match the same format "M=01".

```
$results = Result::orderBy("created_at", "asc")
->whereBetween('created_at', array($from, $to))
->get()
->groupBy(function($date) use($interval) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format("Y ".$interval);
});
```